# Как правильно запускать асинхронный метод в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

С использованием `Dispatcher.Invoke()` и асинхронного метода:

```
public async void InitObservableCollection()
{
    var listFromDAL = await Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Context.GetListAsync());
    listFromDAL.ToList().ForEach(i => MyObservableCollection.Add(new Model(i)));
}
```

Либо без него, запуская синхронный метод через `Task.Factory.StartNew()`:

```
 public async void InitObservableCollection()
 {
     var listFromDAL = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Context.GetList());
     listFromDAL.ToList().ForEach(i => MyObservableCollection.Add(new Model(i)));
 }
```

Оба варианта работают, особой разницы я не вижу.

Comment: А вы её замеряли, разницу то?

Comment: @Monk, нет, не замерял. Просто, насколько я знаю, Dispatcher.Invoke() выполняет переданный ему в делегате метод синхронно. Так в чём тогда его смысл, если можно использовать Task. Или же Task также блокирует вызывающий поток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dispatcher.Invoke` - это вообще не запуск задачи в фоновом потоке - а возвращение из фонового потока в поток UI. То есть этот метод на самом деле делает совершенно противоположное тому, что нужно вам.

`Task.Factory.StartNew`, как и `Task.Run` - это запуск задачи в другом потоке. Можно было бы использовать этот вариант, если бы не было варианта проще.

Но до самого простого варианта вы почему-то не догадались. Не надо ничего придумывать, все уже реализовано!

```
public async void InitObservableCollection()
{
    var listFromDAL = await Context.GetListAsync();
    listFromDAL.ToList().ForEach(i => MyObservableCollection.Add(new Model(i)));
}
```